# How to removing package in custom build?

Tags: android, makefile, android-make

I'm developer base on Qualcomm platform.

I'm wondering if there's an easy way to define which packages are made in build,and I've set up my own patch,like below:

```
`git diff target/product/core.mk
diff --git a/target/product/core.mk b/target/product/core.mk
old mode 100644
new mode 100755
index 519dbb8..f6ff8af
--- a/target/product/core.mk
+++ b/target/product/core.mk
@@ -21,38 +21,18 @@
 # core_tiny.mk in addition to core_minimal.mk.
 PRODUCT_PACKAGES += \
-    BasicDreams \
-    Browser \
-    Calculator \
-    Calendar \
-    CalendarProvider \
     CaptivePortalLogin \
-    CertInstaller \
-    Contacts \
-    DeskClock \
     FusedLocation \
     InputDevices \
     KeyChain \
     Keyguard \
-    LatinIME \
     MmsService
 $(call inherit-product, $(SRC_TARGET_DIR)/product/core_base.mk)
`
```

This patch work well during make a single ROM

## QUESTION

Can we add a **flag** such as  *PLATFORM_VERSION* and *TARGET_BUILD_VARIANT* to control which APP need remove? like below:

`ifeq ($(strip $(flag_need_remove)),true)
    PRODUCT_PACKAGES -= \
        Browser \
        Calculator`

**-=**    **NOT**     **+=**

## I means:

if choose A product,  need remove some apps like *Browser* *Calculator* ,etc.

if choose B product,  NOT remove any apps

**A** and **B** differentiated during **choosecombo**

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

In your device definition, don't include target/product/core.mk. Instead in your device defenition device/// project write a custom ".mk" file with products you want.

Comment: Thanks your feedback!  **LOCAL_OVERRIDES_PACKAGES** flags can be use for this feature!